# Why are my pickled objects not restoring?

Tags: python

So I'm working on a text-based RPG and am fairly new to coding just started learning python about a month ago so if someone could help they would be a lifesaver.

When I save and load my game it loads my default player stats how do I make it load the stat increases and also my potions and gold reset to default as well.

```
class Player:
    name = "Razor"
    atkl = 15
    atkh = 20
    magic_light_slashl = 20
    magic_light_slashh = 25
    magic_fireballl = 40
    magic_fireballh = 48
    magic_lightningl = 55
    magic_lightningh = 65
    maxhp = 50
    hp = 50
    maxap = 10
    ap = 10
    exp = 0
    level = 1
    gold = 20
    potions = 0
    great_potions = 0
    max_potions = 0
    elixers = 0
    great_elixers = 0
    max_elixers = 0

def save():
    player = Player
    level_state = Player.level
    with open('savefile', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump([player, level_state], f, protocol=2)
        print("Game has been saved.")
        start_up()

def load():
    if os.path.exists('savefile') == True:
        with open('savefile', 'rb') as f:
            player, level_state = pickle.load(f)
            print("Loaded save state.")
            start_up()
    else:
        print("Could not find save file.")
        main()
```

and here is a bit of how I level up.

```
def level_up():
    if Player.level == 1:
        if Player.exp >= 30 and Player.exp < 80:
            print("You are level 2")
            Player.level = 2
            Player.atkl = 17
            Player.atkh = 22
            Player.magic_light_slashl = 23
            Player.magic_light_slashh = 27
            Player.maxhp = 53
            Player.hp = 53
            Player.maxap = 12
            Player.ap = 12
```

If you need more of my code to help me just ask.

Comment: Please include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces some error you want to fix. You should probably be using *instance* properties instead of *class* properties as you are currently doing.

Comment: We don't need more of your code, we need less of it. The minimal amount of code that exposes your problem. It will also help you clarify what your problem is and maybe (probably in this case) solve it by yourself.

Answer (score 3):

You're misunderstanding how classes work. You're using class-level properties, rather than instance-level properties, which is causing them to not pickle correctly. You're essentially treating a class as if it were a dictionary and that's fundamentally not how they work.

When you create a class it acts like a blueprint. A blueprint for a car can be used to create many car "instances", but the blueprint isn't a car itself.

So in order to get an instance out of your `Player` class, you need to "instantiate" it. You do this by calling the class by name with parenthesis `()` after it. The parenthesis indicate to Python that you're calling the class' constructor which is defined as `__init__()` inside your class. Your class has no constructor so should first define one.

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        # this is the constructor

        # let's add some instance-level properties
        self.name = 'Razor'
        # you can add the rest of your properties here as long as they being with self

        print 'I am a new instance of the player class, my name is ' + self.name
```

You can then instantiate this and store the instance in a variable like this (note that our message will print during construction):

```
player = Player()
```

You can then access the properties on that instance

```
print player.name
```

Or you can change them

```
player.name = 'Blade'
print player.name
# prints 'Blade'
```

The reason this instantiation is useful and important is that it lets you create as many "players" (or characters, or enemies, etc.) as you want, and they all retain their own properties. `self` is a clear indicator that you're talking to the instance, and not the class itself.